# Can this native sql be done using criteria or HQL?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, criteria

I am not that good enough to convert this native mysql query to either using Criteria or HQL.

Here is the query

```
SELECT SUM(temp.hours) FROM 
(SELECT IF(a.status=TRUE,a.column1,
    IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,a.date1,a.date2)/60,0) )
AS hours FROM appointment AS a) AS temp;
```

My only one problem of doing this in HQL is that HQL doesnot support TIMESTAMPDIFF. I think this is doable in criteria by breaking them in two different criteria. First we can sum column1 and then sum diff of date1 and date2 and then sum the final result but how to do `TIMESTAMPDIFF` in criteria?